# How to pass the password to the jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a java class where it requires the password of an user which is stored in the local machine of the user, when i trigger the build in master Jenkins, build is failed due to the authentication where it searching for the user password which is not available in the machine.How can i make it generics to the Jenkins to get the build successful.

Comment: JunitTestCase:  private static final String PASSWORD_FILE_PATH = "U:/authentication/pw.txt";String password = Files.readFirstLine(new File(PASSWORD_FILE_PATH), Charset.defaultCharset());
    if ((password == null) || (password.length() == 0)) {
      throw new IOException("Reading file at \"U:/authentication/pw.txt\" resulted in a null or empty password.");
    }

Comment: Do you hard code the string ```"U:/authentication/pw.txt"```?

Comment: Yes, its in my local system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [Environment Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) instead of hard code.

Example:

For each machine, set this variable first

- Your local

  `set PATH_TO_MY_PASSWORD="U:/authentication/pw.txt"`
- Jenkins

  `set PATH_TO_MY_PASSWORD="C:/my_jenkins/pw.txt"`

Then change your code to:

```
private static final String PASSWORD_FILE_PATH = System.getenv("PATH_TO_MY_PASSWORD");
```